# Upboard can not acces pins

Tags: linux, io, export, ubuntu-16.04, upboard

I have 2 different intel UpBoards. Both have 40 pins. I have tried to access pins using:

```
 echo 26 > /sys/class/gpio/export
 echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio26/direction
 echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio26/value
```

These commands let us to configure physical pin 37(Linux GPIO number 26) [from this link](https://wiki.up-community.org/Pinout)

My first upboard is working with these commands very well. And when I run the command:

```
 ls /sys/class/gpio/
```

the output:

```
 gpiochip0 gpiochip267 gpiochip310 gpiochip357 gpiochip434 export unexport
```

But when I run the same command in other upboard the output is:

```
 export gpiochip225 gpiochip228 gpiochip314 gpiochip341 gpiochip414 unexport
```

As we see from the output the second one doesn't have gpiochip0. And I think this occurs the problem why pins are not accesable. Because the other gpiochip files are not for 40 pins upboard. How can I fix this problem. The same problem is also mentioned here but no solution. [same problem](https://forum.up-community.org/discussion/1277/40-pin-hat-i-o-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was about that I didnt add the repository. I just installed Ubuntu and I didn't do the next step which is in [here](http://wiki.up-community.org/Ubuntu#Install_Ubuntu_kernel_for_UP_from_PPA) The necessary steps are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubilinux/up
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge 'linux-.*generic'
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-upboard
sudo reboot
```